# Redirect users in first login to a dynamic link

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm using a gravityform user registration to handle registration processes , and i use gravityform custom post type + wp resume manger .. to let the user submit some fields in his resume within the registration process .. the user register, fill some fields , and these fields he put is mapped to his resume fields "not all of them" , the resume is just a post.

this above is just a brief about what i'm doing here

what i need is :

now the user is registered , and posted his resume and filed some of their fields .. i want to redirect him in the first login to his resume edit page to fill the rest of fields

this is the link :

http://my domain name/complete-your-resume(static-page)/?action=edit&resume_id=7038

i already know how to redirect users in first login .. 
what i don't how to do is 1- how to redirect them to "their" resume-post edit page
2- redirect them based in their role .. i want to redirect only users who have role X in the first login 
3- if there a way to prevent them to navigate anywhere till they fill all fields and save the post/resume

i will highly appreciate any help of these points above.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per your explanation you want that user should fill there resume first and then allowed to go elsewhere in the app and also a role based control. For this

1) Make a framework by using class where you authenticate a user and set their role in global variable. Which can  be accessed from any where of the application. Also set a variable in this class suppose:

```
    $resFilled = 0;
    if (// resume is completed){
    $refilled =1;
     }
```

This is a general example. Give some code so that we can help you specifically.

Comment: thanks for your response ,the main issue now is the first login redirect , 1,2 points . as i explained ,the user filled some fields in his resume within his registration .. the resume is just a custom post type .. have a several fields ,and has a front-end edit form where the user fill the required fields .i made the user fill some of this fields in registration process .so when he will open his resume will find those fields filed .. what i need to do , is to redirect him after he activate his account and login to the full resume form to fill the remained fields .. to the link mentioned above

Comment: this link: http://mydomainname/complete-your-resume(static-page)/?action=edit&resume_id=7038
which (7038) is the id number of the user's resume-post

Comment: It's easy for us  when you provide some code that you have written here for help . Your requirements can be fulfilled but show us your code, where we could start from ..

Comment: actually i haven't write any custom code for this till now , i'm using the frontend mentioned plugins . the resumes are stored in wp_posts table , in the ID column there's the user's resume-post id which i want to redirect the user to it in the first login .. what i need simply , is the required code to redirect user to this link http://mydomainname/complete-your-resume(static-page)/?action=edit&resume_id=7038 .which (7038) is the user first post .and this post type name is (resume )